# How to use document in qwik. Getting document of undefined

Tags: javascript, qwik, qwikjs

How to access document in Qwik js. Getting document of undefined when trying to use `document.getElementBtId` in a `component$`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can also see the problem and help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access to the document object only in browser client side.

You have to use it in a [useVisibleTask](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/lifecycle/#usevisibletask) function which is called when document becomes visible in browser.

```
export const ExampleComponent = component$(() => {

  useVisibleTask$(() => {

    // Only runs in the client
    const element = document.getElementById("your-id") 

  });

  return <div id="your-id">Example component</div>;
});
```